# xtable output doesn't look like a table

Tags: r, xtable

I'd like to use the xtable package to make a neat table for a report.

Using the code on pg 7 of http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/Sweave/foo.pdf, I get some output but it doesn't look anything like the table they get.

This is what I get:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.3.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Sat Jul 14 20:49:29 2018
\begin{table}[tbp]
\centering
\caption{MyIris Table} 
\label{tab:one}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
 & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width \\ 
  \hline
1 & 5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 \\ 
  2 & 4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 \\ 
  3 & 4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 \\ 
  4 & 4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 \\ 
  5 & 5.0 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 \\ 
  6 & 5.4 & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for any help!

```
# Select toy data 
iris
my_iris <- iris[1:6,1:4]

# Turn to matrix  
my_iris_mat <- as.matrix(my_iris)

# Try to make table 
<<label=tab1,echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(my_iris_mat, caption = "MyIris Table", label = "tab:one",
             digits = c(1, 1, 1, 1,1)), table.placement = "tbp",
      caption.placement = "top")
```

Comment: Can you please copy paste the table output.

Comment: it works for me

Comment: You don't really say what happens?? do you get an error? what code are you using to run it, or are you clicking the compile button in rstudio. Are you using knitr or sweave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and compiled the .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[tbp]
\centering
\caption{MyIris Table} 
\label{tab:one}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
 & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width \\ 
  \hline
1 & 5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 \\ 
  2 & 4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 \\ 
  3 & 4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 \\ 
  4 & 4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 \\ 
  5 & 5.0 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 \\ 
  6 & 5.4 & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get this table:

[image]

It seems it is working.